# How to iterate/loop parameters list?

Tags: list, parameters, powerbi, powerquery, each

How to substitute code below with compact loop?

```
let
    ParametersList = {"CustomerID","FirstName","LastName"},
    Source1 = fnCheckId(srcTbl , ParametersList{0}),
    Source2 = fnCheckId(Source1, ParametersList{1}),
    Source3 = fnCheckId(Source2, ParametersList{2}),
    Result = Source3    
in
    Result
```

Looping problems:

1. It should loop ParametersList
2. current loop output table should work as input Table for next loop

Simplified example details ([Source File](https://github.com/DenisSipchenko/Power-BI/blob/main/Questions/how%20to%20iterate%20parameters%20list.xlsx)):

`fnCheckId` function example (in real business case much more complex):

```
(tbl as table, clm as text)=>
let   
    //tbl = srcTbl, clm = "FirstName",
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(tbl,"QA "&clm, each if Text.Length(Record.Field(_, clm))>3 then "Ok" else "Nok")    
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Source table:

```
Table.FromRows(
        {
            {1, "Bob", "Smith", "123-4567"},
            {2, "Jim", "Brown", "987-6543"},
            {3, "Paul", "Wick", "543-7890"}
        },
        {"CustomerID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Phone"}
    )
```

[image]

Estimated result table:

[image]

Comment: In addition to comment by @horseyride, a screenshot of your expected results, given your input, would be helpful. Your 1st example only shows code, not a result table in pq or pbi.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Not screenshot, text. The text content is relevant, the gui details are not.

Answer (score 3):

With original function, how about

```
let srcTbl = Table.FromRows(
    {
        {1, "Bob", "Smith", "123-4567"},
        {2, "Jim", "Brown", "987-6543"},
        {3, "Paul", "Wick", "543-7890"}
    },
    {"CustomerID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Phone"}
),
List = {"CustomerID", "FirstName", "LastName"},
#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns" = Table.Unpivot(srcTbl, List, "Attribute", "Value"),
Source1 = fnCheckId(#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns","Value"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source1,{"Value"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"QA Value", "Value"}}),
#"Change Title" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Attribute",each "QA" & _, type text}}),
combined =  #"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns" & #"Change Title",
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(combined,{{"Attribute", type text}, {"Value", type text}}) ,
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

or with changed function as below,

```
let srcTbl = Table.FromRows(
    {
        {1, "Bob", "Smith", "123-4567"},
        {2, "Jim", "Brown", "987-6543"},
        {3, "Paul", "Wick", "543-7890"}
    },
    {"CustomerID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Phone"}
),
List = {"CustomerID", "FirstName", "LastName"},
#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns" = Table.Unpivot(srcTbl, List, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns",{{"Value", type text}}),
#"Processed" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Value",each fnCheckId2(_), type text}}),
Namechange = Table.TransformColumns(Processed,{{"Attribute",each "QA "&_, type text}}),
combined = #"Changed Type1" & Namechange,
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(combined, List.Distinct(combined[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

with  **fnCheckId2**

```
( clm as text)=>
let   
z = if  Text.Length(clm )>3 then "Ok" else "Nok"
in z
```

Comment: beautiful, thank you!  
But still the question: is it possible to iterate function "blindly" (as black box) using `each _` syntax?  
The question is more about `each _`  use scenarios (this syntax is still a bit like "blackmagic" for me)?  P.S. the answer "No, not possible" is perfect as well - I'll just relax & leave it... :)

Comment: the top way, yes, it is blind as to the function contents, just operating on unpivot

Answer (score 0):

Please try this loop example:

1. **loops** `ParametersList` list
2. Use `fnCheckId` function **output table as input for next loop**
3. Do **NOT** require **knowledge about** looping function **fnCheckId**

Recursive **function** *Loop_fnCheckId*:

```
(Loop as number, inTbl as table, inPrm as list )=>
try       Loop_fnCheckId(Loop-1, fnCheckId(inTbl, inPrm{Loop-1}),inPrm)
otherwise inTbl
```

code with **loop**:

```
let 
    ParametersList = {"CustomerID","FirstName","LastName"},    
    cntLoop = List.Count(ParametersList),
    Result = Loop_fnCheckId(cntLoop,srcTbl, ParametersList)
in  Result
```

P.S. The question: is it possible to rewrite it using `each _` syntax and avoid additional looping function *Loop_fnCheckId*